# Powershell Command to set Inbound Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Rules

Tags: windows, powershell, firewall

I trying to implement the Predefined Inbound rules Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) via powershell.  I have tried

```
    netsh advfirewall set service RemoteAdmin enable
    netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes
```

But do not see these changes reflected in the Local Group Policy editor.  Has any tried to do this or something similar?

Comment: Unless you're using a really old OS you can use the NetSecurity module and just use `Set-NetFirewallRule` to do this without an external executable. Could the netsh command be case sensitive for the rule name? Are you running PowerShell as Administrator?

Comment: Its not case sensitive and yes I'm running it as admin.  I found the command on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822854(v=vs.85).aspx